# Subtracting the difference on the last quantity if sufficient

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to subtract the difference of the **qty2-qty3** for each **materialId** on **qty1** if its sufficient, if not just leave at least 10 on the last **qty1** and subtract the remaining qty on the other items.

Here's my sample data.

```
DECLARE @items TABLE(qty1 INT, qty2 INT, qty3 INT,  marks INT,  material varchar(300));
INSERT INTO @items (qty1, qty2, qty3, marks,  material)
VALUES
(120, 320, null, 10,  'a')
,(60, 320, null, 20,  'a')
,(80, 320, null,  30, 'a')
,(60, 320, 50,  40,  'a')

,(120, 320, null,  10,  'b')
,(60, 320, null,  20,  'b')
,(80, 320, null,  30,  'b')
,(60, 320, 300, 40, 'b')
```

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
select case when  qty2 > qty3 and qty3 is not null then 
            case when qty1 > (qty2-qty3) then
                qty1 - (qty2-qty3)
            else
                lead(qty1-qty3) OVER (PARTITION BY materialId ORDER BY marks) 
            end
        else
            qty1
        end as finalQty, material
     from @items
```

Expected Result:

```
20      a
10      a
10      a
10      a
120     b
60      b
80      b
40      b
```

Comment: This looks like a Supply vs Demand type problem - have a [read of this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2022/01/t-sql-queries/supply-demand-solutions-1)